# Python 3.10.8 TypeError: TypedDict does not support instance and class checks

Tags: python, typing, typeddict

After having created the a typeddict, I am experiencing the following error:

> TypeError: TypedDict does not support instance and class checks

Below is a MWE

```py
"""Entry point for this project, runs the project code based on the cli command
that invokes this script."""

print('hello world')
from typeguard import typechecked
import sys
from typing import Dict, List, Union

if sys.version_info < (3, 11):
    from typing_extensions import NotRequired, TypedDict
else:
    from typing import NotRequired


class Run_config(TypedDict):
    adaptation: Union[None, Dict]
    algorithm: Dict
    iteration: int
    graph_size: int
    graph_nr: int
    radiation: Union[None, Dict]
    seed: int
    simulator: str
    export_images: NotRequired[bool]
    export_types: NotRequired[List[str]]
    max_duration: NotRequired[int]
    overwrite_snn_creation: NotRequired[bool]
    overwrite_snn_propagation: NotRequired[bool]
    overwrite_visualisation: NotRequired[bool]
    overwrite_sim_results: NotRequired[bool]
    show_snns: NotRequired[bool]

@typechecked
def some_function( some_int:int, run_config: Run_config) -> Run_config:
    """Returns a dict"""
    print(f'some_int={some_int}')
    return run_config

some_run_config:Run_config = {
    "adaptation":None,
    "algorithm":{"hi":2},
    "iteration":5,
    "graph_size":4,
    "graph_nr":6,
    "radiation":None,
    "seed":2,
    "simulator":"hello",
}
some_int:int =5
some_function(some_int,some_run_config)
```

That throws as output the above error. The stacktrace is:

```
$python -m src.mwe
hello world
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/name/anaconda/envs/snncompare/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/home/name/anaconda/envs/snncompare/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/name/git/snn/mwe/src/mwe/__main__.py", line 50, in <module>
    some_function(some_int,some_run_config)
  File "/home/name/anaconda/envs/snncompare/lib/python3.10/site-packages/typeguard/__init__.py", line 1032, in wrapper
    check_argument_types(memo)
  File "/home/name/anaconda/envs/snncompare/lib/python3.10/site-packages/typeguard/__init__.py", line 875, in check_argument_types
    raise TypeError(*exc.args) from None
TypeError: TypedDict does not support instance and class checks
```

### Question

Why does this error occur, and how can I resolve it?

Comment: You **must** provide a [mcve]

Comment: Thank you for your kind suggestion, I took the liberty to include a reproducable MWE that outputs the specified error message.

Comment: OK, this seems like an issue with the `typeguard` library (a crucial details) which seems to rely on the type annotations being *actual types*, but `TypeDict` is not, it exists merely for type hinting.